# PSA: please flag spam as spam

Tags: discussion, flagging

Emacs is not a topic where many people have something to sell. So we don't get topical spam on this site. But as with any website that accepts external contributions, we get generic spam.

**When you see spam, please [flag](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) it as “[spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-rude-or-abusive-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-wor/58035#58035)”**! Posts are automatically deleted if they receive 6 spam flags. Additionally, accounts that have been identified as [posting spam](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/mod-spam) are blocked from posting.

Please do *not* downvote spam, or flag is as low quality. Doing this reduces the chances that it will be seen by 6 users who can flag it as spam, and so delays the time until the post get deleted.

#### How do I recognize spam?

On this site, spam is typically not obviously trying to see you something.  <sub>(Psst, I have some quality Lisp functions! Half price for you, today only!)</sub>  Most spammers aren't trying to convince people who read their post. They're trying to get referenced in search engines.

Often, spam in answers copy sentence fragments from the question, to make it not immediately obvious that the post doesn't actually contain any on-topic content. Somewhere in that post is a link to the site where the spammer is selling whatever is trending — pharmaceuticals, house shares or whatever. These days many spams are scams — they aren't trying to make people buy something, they're trying to get people's credit card details, or to convince people to install malware in order to take control of their computers and turn them into cryptocurrency miners, use them to spread malware, or even install Vi! Tip: if someone offers you tech support, they're probably trying to get you to install their malware.

Note: some spammer's sites contain malware that exploits browser bugs to install itself without user intervention. So avoid clicking on links in spam posts.

So please flag these support scam posts as spam!